# Savoury equivalent of choco-cornflake cakes

Tags: substitutions, chocolate, pastry

I'm currently trying to work out a savoury equivalent to chocolate to allow the creation of a non-sweet version of [chocolate cornflake cakes](http://uktv.co.uk/food/recipe/aid/533902%20Chocolate%20cornflake%20cakes).

Currently the best equivalent of chocolate (in terms of melting point and water content) that I can think of is cheese. Another alternative would be to use egg and bake the cornflake cakes to get the egg to set.

Before I set off and possibly create a cheese and cornflake omelette, I wanted to check if there is an ingredient or technique that I've overlooked which would cement the cornflakes together without making them too soggy or burning them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to a macaroon, whip egg whites with cream of tartar and season with whatever savory spices and herbs you might like before folding with the corn flakes, corn chips, or crushed tortilla chips, and then bake at a low temperature until crisp and dry but not browned.

Answer (score 2):

Peanut Butter, cream cheese, or mashed potatoes (maybe mashed sweet potatoes) come to mind.

Consider adding gelatin to the mixture to help it set and possibly help the corn flakes not get as soggy as they possibly would.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than lose the chocolate in the recipe, you could lose the corn syrup and add some chili's and a small amount of peanut butter as your new binder.  You actually wouldn't even need the peanut butter as the dark chocolate should refirm quite easily in the fridge.  This would be a take off on the mexican [mole sauce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(sauce)